# Calculate the area of a regular polygon issue

Tags: java, pi

I am trying to write a bit of code to calculate the area of a regular polygon with this formula (sides*length^2)/4*tan(Pi/sides) my code looks like

```
double area = (nSides * Math.pow(sLength, 2)) /
            4 * Math.tan ((Math.PI) / nSides);
```

I expected that with nSides == 5 and sLength == 6.5, I should get 72.69017017488385 but it outputs 38.370527260283126 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [Order of Operations](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+order+of+operations).  The Java documentation says it unclearly [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):

> The operators in the following table are listed according to precedence order

The problem is that division and multiplication have equal precedence.

> Operators on the same line have equal precedence. ... All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right;

So given they have equal precedence, your division by 4 will be evaluated before the multiplication by `Math.tan`.  You need to explicitly specify the order by inserting an extra set of brackets:

```
double area = (nSides * Math.pow(sLength, 2)) /
              (4 * Math.tan ((Math.PI) / nSides));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use addition parenthesis for your denominator

```
(4 * Math.tan ((Math.PI) / nSides))
```

Else java thinks that you're multiplying the entire expression by `Math.tan ((Math.PI) / nSides)`.

```
double area = (nSides * Math.pow(sLength, 2)) /
         (4 * Math.tan ((Math.PI) / nSides));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case any one need to calculate the area and perimeter of regular polygon using OOP concept here is my trial. Somebody is asking me such for school assignment and this is what i try to solve. I am a student and want to be a programmer and happy to learn and share knowledge.

Regular Polygon is a shape with the 3 or more sides. each side must be equal in length. formula for calculating area is different based on the number of sides.

> Square area = length of side * length of side;
>   Triangle = length of side * length of side * sqrt (3) / 4

In C# my code seems the following but i apply the concept of oop as much as possible and i also implement factory design pattern. I will code it in java too.

This is interface IRegularPolygon and in this problem i used interface instead of abstract data types.

```
public interface IRegularPolygon
    {
        int NumberOfSides { get; set; }
        double SideLength { get; set; }
        double getPerimeter();
        double getArea();

    }
// you can also use abstract class the code is as follows 
public abstract class RegularPolygon
    {
        public int NumberOfSides { get; set; }
        public double SideLength { get; set; }
        public double getPerimeter()
        {
          return NumberOfSides * SideLength;
        }
        public double getArea();
    }

//The Square class that implement IRegularPolygon interface
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RegularPolygon.BL
{
    public class Square : IRegularPolygon
    {
        public  int NumberOfSides { get; set; }
        public  double SideLength { get; set; }
        public Square(double SideLength)
        {
            this.NumberOfSides=4;
            this.SideLength = SideLength;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the Perimeter of the square
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public double getPerimeter()
        {
            return NumberOfSides * SideLength;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the area of a square
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public double getArea()
        {
            return SideLength * SideLength;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}-{1}", "Area of Sqare:" + getArea(), "Perimeter Of Sqaure :" + getPerimeter());
        }

    }
}

//The EquilateralTriangle class that implement IRegularPolygon interface
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RegularPolygon.BL
{
    public class EquilateralTriangle : IRegularPolygon
    {
        public  int NumberOfSides { get; set; }
        public  double SideLength { get; set; }
        public EquilateralTriangle(double SideLength)
        {
            this.NumberOfSides=3;
            this.SideLength = SideLength;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the Perimeter of EquilateralTriangle
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public double getPerimeter()
        {
            return NumberOfSides * SideLength;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the area of EquilateralTriangle
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public double getArea()
        {
            return SideLength * SideLength * Math.Sqrt(3) / 4;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}-{1}", "Area of Sqare:" + getArea(), "Perimeter Of Sqaure :" + getPerimeter());
        }

    }
}

//The RegularPentagon class that implement IRegularPolygon interface
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RegularPolygon.BL
{
    public class RegularPentagon : IRegularPolygon
    {
        public  int NumberOfSides { get; set; }
        public  double SideLength { get; set; }
        public double Apothem { get; set; }

        public RegularPentagon(double SideLength, double Apothem)
        {    
            this.NumberOfSides = 5;
            this.SideLength = SideLength;
            this.Apothem = Apothem;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the Perimeter of RegularPentagon
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public double getPerimeter()
        {
            return NumberOfSides * SideLength;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the area of RegularPentagon
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public double getArea()
        {
            return 2.5 * SideLength * Apothem;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}-{1}", "Area of Sqare:" + getArea(), "Perimeter Of Sqaure :" + getPerimeter());
        }

    }
}
// RegPolygonFactory class is a factory class that instantiate object based on shape 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RegularPolygon.BL
{
    public class RegPolygonFactory
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Create instance of an object based on the type of shape 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="shapeType"></param>
        /// <param name="side"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IRegularPolygon getShape(string shapeType, double sideLength)
        {
            return getShape(shapeType, sideLength, 0.0);
        }
        public IRegularPolygon getShape(string shapeType, double sideLength, double apothem)
        {
            if (shapeType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("shapeType");
            if (sideLength < 0.0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(sideLength.ToString());
            if (apothem < 0.0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(apothem.ToString());
            else if (shapeType.Equals("SQUARE"))
            {
                return new Square(sideLength);
            }
            else if (shapeType.Equals("EQUILATERALTRIANGLE"))
            {
                return new EquilateralTriangle(sideLength);
            }
            //shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("REGULARPENTAGON")
            else if (shapeType.Equals("REGULARPENTAGON"))
            {
                return new RegularPentagon(sideLength, apothem);
            }
            return null;
        }


    }
}

//For unit Test: To test for instance square
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using RegularPolygon.BL;

namespace RegularPolygonTest.BL
{
    [TestClass]
    public class SquareTest
    {
        RegPolygonFactory regularPolygon = new RegPolygonFactory();

        /// <summary>
        /// Test the Area Of Square with valid input(side=4)
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod]
        public void getAreaOfSquare_ValidArgument()
        {
            //Arrange
            double sideLength = 4;
            var square = regularPolygon.getShape("SQUARE", sideLength);
            var expected = sideLength * sideLength;
            //Act
            var actual = square.getArea();

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
    /// <summary>
        /// Test the Perimeter Of Square with valid input(side=6, edges=4)
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod]
        public void getPerimeterOfSquare_ValidAregument()
        {
            //Arrange
            double sideLength = 6;
            double NumberOfSides = 4;
            var square = regularPolygon.getShape("SQUARE", sideLength);
            var expected = sideLength * NumberOfSides;
            //Act
            var actual = square.getPerimeter();

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Test the Perimeter Of Square with invalid input(edges=6)
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod]
        public void getPerimeterOfSquare_InValidPostiveAregument()
        {
            //Arrange
            double sideLength = 5;
            double NumberOfSides = 6;
            var square = regularPolygon.getShape("SQUARE", sideLength);
            var expected = sideLength * NumberOfSides;
            //Act
            var actual = square.getPerimeter();

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's actually a specific formula that you can use to calculate areas of arbitrary-sided regular polygons: `A=s^2*n*cot(180°/n)/2`.